# Set Spinner item with espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, ui-testing, android-espresso

I want to know how to set an item in a spinner in espresso testing.

```
onView(withId(R.id.spinner_gender)).perform(click());
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)))).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

This code above does not work :/

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615658/espresso-why-dont-spinners-close-after-selection/37683354#37683354 Its down voted but it really worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet looks correct, so there may be an issue with another part of your test class?
Are you getting an Exception or stack-trace you can update your question with? Also check the espresso [documentation](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/basics/) for a bit more explaination.

See small code example of how you can select a spinner option by text or it's position.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class BasicEspressoTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> testRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void selectBySpinnerPosition() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click());
        onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)))).atPosition(0).perform(click());
    }

    @Test
    public void selectBySpinnerText() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.spinner)).perform(click());
        onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is("spinner's text"))).perform(click());
    }
}
```